# Q1Q2Q3Q4 coupling in qubo file

Tags: annealing

According to the question [Q1Q2Q3 coupling in qubo file](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5637) we can couple 3 qbits. When it comes with 4 qbits like q1q2q3q4, how should set this 4-qbit element to qubo file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique of reduction by substitution.
Here we represent using ancilla representing a Boolean constraint $ z\Leftrightarrow x_1\wedge x_2 $ as a quadratic penalty function :
$$P(x_1,x_2;z) = x_1 x_2 - 2(x_1+x_2)z + 3z$$

For a triplet interaction, you use it to reduce to pairwise :
$$ x_1 x_2 x_3 = \min_z \bigl\{ z x_3 + M P(x_1,x_2;z) \bigr\}, M>1 $$

For higher degrees, you can sequentially define ancilla variables in order to reduce terms by one until you have pairwise interactions. Again, this is explained in the D-Wave documentation.